# Fix a recurring MySQL table error automatically

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I run one of my sites on Drupal 7 and there's an occasional error with `watchdog` table, which gets corrupted.

I tried to install a module that would fix that but it's not really doing the job, so I have to manually run

`REPAIR TABLE watchdog USE_FRM`

from time to time to fix that table and make the site work again.

Do you know how I could run a script that would regularly check if the table is corrupt and automatically fix it using the command above?

I know the question is a bit general but that why I'm asking it, so that I can get more specific with this issue...

Thank you!

Comment: I would rather find out why the table gets corrupted and resolve the issue once and for all.

Comment: You can check with this article: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/